# Looking for tactics for dealing with pytesseract output

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

There are a lot of unanswered questions on Tesseract and wrapper pytesseract. But here goes.

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import pytesseract

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
image = "C:\\ocr\\target\\31832_226140__0001-00004.jpg"

custom_config = r'--dpi 72 --oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,\'\/- "'
# pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
pytestFolder = 'C:\\ocr\\increment_testing\\'

with open('{fn}debugTestLang1downAdjUp.txt'.format(fn=pytestFolder),'w') as f:
    f.write(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config=custom_config))
```

I'm using

```
tesseract 5.3.0.20221222
pip freeze pytesseract.git@1ec07b1c9411ca58e5e3f05b0100f6bb0e8447ce
```

The example file, is one of a lot of image files that will be processed, is a 72ppi grayscale historical document of high contrast.

[image: Electoral Roll 1981]

The image data type is: uint8, Height is: 2537, Width is: 3640. The bit depth of image is: 2

I have written Python scripts for:

- splitting and cropping the image into separate pages and columns
- de-skewing (as you can see the left hand page is on a slight angle)
- resizing
- performing Gaussian blur, Otsu's thresholding etc

These don't really alter the bigger issue.

Using the simple script above on the 'raw' image I can get close to all lines of the image file content. There are many wrong characters but the overall result is okay by me.

```
REFERENCE ONLY
ALLAN-ANKER PENCARROW COMPOSITE ROLL PAGE 2 PAGE 3 PENCARROW COMPOSITE ROLL ANKER-ATKINSON
001 ALLAN, Wehom ROSS oo... 13 Kowhai Street, Wainuiomata,Greenkeeper 101 ANDERSON, Jean Elaine .........sseecreceeececeeteeeessss 1 Chanel Grove,Lower Clerk ANKER.
002 ALLARDYCE. Margaret isabel ..............89 Bell Roed,Lower Hutt,Housewife 102 ANDERSON, Joanatte Eo. crcsrncnvn. 16 Burden TuWencanas ig cerry pedi rans cacy ear ter iy Poor linn silted aga nen aR gle lated So st
003 ALLARDYCE, Mervyn George ............--..49 Bell Road, Lower Hutt,Company Mrgr 103 ANDERSON, Jeffrey Wilfred ....................288 Webwhetu Rd,Lower Hut.Bnk Clk FM 003 ANKER. Lewis Richard .......................4 Bledisloe Cr, Wainucomate Sales Clerk NAMA Sea ee J Donnelley Dave Wesnuiomata,Pub, Servent
004 ALLCOCK, George Mckinney ....s..n--.-0.41 Peel Place, Wainuiomata Scientist 104 ANDERSON, Jessie Faith ...................1/220 Warwhetu Road.Lower Hutt. Retired 004 ANKER, Robert James 368 We Rosa i HDR AOIY 'oorctoenincineed Donnelley Drive. Weinuiometa, Saleewomen
005 ALLCOCK. Shittey Constance 41 Peel Place, Weinuiomata Married 105 ANDERSON, John Gilbert... -1s.cnsrsenenn 65 Riverside Dr S,Lower Hutt,Tex Whr ae ARURRLEN se esse ee LINEAR VR gga 5 Wememiceter Roe W/rauerrara her ere
```

If I split the image file into separate pages and increase the image file pixel height of the text, by increasing the resolution of the image file. I get a better quality of result.

```
ALLAN-ANKER PENCARROW COMPOSITE ROLL PAGE 2
001 ALLAN, Witham ROSS ...u.......cs.ccsses 13 Kowhai Street, Wainuiomata,Greenkesper 101 ANDERSON, Jean Elaine .............0.csecssccecsseesse I Chanel Grove,Lower Hutt, Clerk
002 ALLARDYCE, Margaret Isabel ............................49 Bell Road,Lower Hutt, Housewife 102 ANDERSON, Jesnatte E ......eeccssn.s1 168 Burden Av,Weinuiomat gi Sorry ff
003 ALLARDYCE, Mervyn George .....................49 Bell Road,Lower Hutt,Company Mngr 103 ANDERSON, Jeffrey Wilfred ...........00.0-----288 Waiwhetu Rd,Lower Hutt.Bnk Clik
006 ALLEN, Albert Robert 0... 48 Coast Road, Wainuiomate Retired 106 ANDERSON, Joyce Lequesnoy ........................ 18 Bumside St,Lower Hutt. Housewife
007 ALLEN. Anthony Besumont ...........6.0-.--37 Kotan Rosd,Days Bry,Accounts Ofr 107 ANDERSON, Judith .................-............81 Waiwhetu Road,Lower Hutt,Housekeeper ff
008 ALLEN, Anthony James... ..e00.--27 Dover Road,WainuiomataElectro-Frmr 108 ANDERSON, Kathleen Mary ..........................27 Rossiter Avenue,Lower HuttRetired
O10 ALLEN, Colleen Mary .scccscsccseesecseereseniee-s fi Hine Road, Wainuiomata.Admin Asst. 110 ANDERSON, Linda Vicki ............-..s00.0.12 Kaun Street,Eastbourne,Mother Wife 5
```

But. There are missing lines. And not lines of inferior quality. Because these lines are random. If I keep cutting the image down into just the columns (increasing resolution of these) I'm getting different output for different image file edits. For example entry `005` may be missing from a single page file but is present for a column 1 edit.

At this stage it looks like I will have to 'collect' the text lines from different edits. By OCRing a combination of double page, single page or column to get each text listing. Because I have looked through the docs and across a lot of questions on SO.

Unless someone knows how to increase resolution without loosing lines?

Comment: why is that data thresholded already? please show unfiltered source data.

Comment: I thank you for your interest. If you are talking about the `custom_config`? Then I would simply say that it is necessary. Otherwise the output useless. The data hasn't been thresholded. It is unfiltered. When I mention Gaussian, Otsu etc. I am talking about tests I have run in separately and in conjunction. But not for this output.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. There is no improvement for single page OCR processing. In fact it gets marginally worse. I have reviewed my old Google OCR process for the same image and it is far better than my first efforts with Tesseract. But that is another story.

Comment: Very bad picture. Can you produce a better one?

Comment: Yes the image is old. But that is just what I have to work with. I have gone back to using Google OCR. Much better than Tesseract.